Seq2SeqTrainer produces incorrect EvalPrediction after changing another Tokenizer
I'm using Seq2SeqTrainer to train my model with a custom tokenizer. The base model is BART Chinese (fnlp/bart-base-chinese). If the original tokenizer of BART Chinese is used, the output is normal. Yet when I swap the tokenizer with another tokenizer that I made, the output of compute_metrics, specifically the preds part of EvalPrediction is incorrect (the decoded text becomes garbage).
The codes are as follows:
model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
model.config.vocab_size = len(tokenizer)

steps = 500 # small value for debug purpose
batch_size = 4
training_args = CustomSeq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir = "my_output_dir",
    evaluation_strategy = IntervalStrategy.STEPS,
    optim = "adamw_torch",
    eval_steps = steps,
    logging_steps = steps,
    save_steps = steps,
    learning_rate = 2e-5,
    per_device_train_batch_size = batch_size,
    per_device_eval_batch_size = batch_size,
    weight_decay = 0.01,
    save_total_limit = 1,
    num_train_epochs = 30,
    predict_with_generate = True,
    remove_unused_columns = False, 
    fp16 = True, # save memory
    metric_for_best_model = "bleu",
    load_best_model_at_end = True,
    report_to = "wandb",
    # HuggingFace Hub related
    hub_token = hf_token,
    push_to_hub = True,
    save_safetensors = True,
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model = model,
    args = training_args,
    train_dataset = tokenized_train_dataset,
    eval_dataset = tokenized_eval_dataset,
    tokenizer = tokenizer,
    data_collator = data_collator,
    compute_metrics = compute_metrics,
    callbacks = [EarlyStoppingCallback(early_stopping_patience=3)],
)

which the tokenizer is my custom tokenizer. The result is normal if my tokenizer uses the original tokenizer (tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)).
For the compute_metrics, it is as follows:
def postprocess_text(preds, labels):
    preds = [pred.strip() for pred in preds]
    labels = [[label.strip()] for label in labels]

    return preds, labels

def compute_metrics(eval_preds):
    preds, labels = eval_preds

    print("Preds and Labels:", preds[0], labels[0])
    
    if isinstance(preds, tuple):
        preds = preds[0]
    decoded_preds = tokenizer.batch_decode(preds, skip_special_tokens=True)

    labels = np.where(labels != -100, labels, tokenizer.pad_token_id)
    decoded_labels = tokenizer.batch_decode(labels, skip_special_tokens=True)

    print("Decoded Preds (before postprocess):", decoded_preds[0])
    print("Decoded Labels (before postprocess):", decoded_labels[0])

    decoded_preds, decoded_labels = postprocess_text(decoded_preds, decoded_labels)
    print("Decoded Preds:", decoded_preds[0])
    print("Decoded Labels:", decoded_labels[0])

    result_bleu = metric_bleu.compute(predictions=decoded_preds, references=decoded_labels, tokenize='zh')
    result_chrf = metric_chrf.compute(predictions=decoded_preds, references=decoded_labels, word_order=2)
    results = {"bleu": result_bleu["score"], "chrf": result_chrf["score"]}

    prediction_lens = [np.count_nonzero(pred != tokenizer.pad_token_id) for pred in preds]
    results["gen_len"] = np.mean(prediction_lens)
    results = {k: round(v, 4) for k, v in results.items()}
    return results

From the debug message, the output sentence does not make sense and consists of weird characters only. I think the model does not recognize the token IDs produced by my custom tokenizer.
How should I tackle this problem? My goal is to train the model with my custom tokenizer.

How exactly does your tokenizer differ from the default one?

dedicated for Chinese language, supports phrases instead of single characters
